# Difference between predict() and predict_proba() functions in scikit learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, statistics, data-science

Greetings data science community! How's going? So, I'm studying classification Tree and scikit-learning and during my studyings i come across this "issue":

After training a tree (clf = DecisionTreeClassifier()) and training it (`clf.fit(Xtrain, ytrain)`) i have decided to test its performance on the training data itself (just to compare, later, with the test data, in terms of Sensitivity Specificity and ROC-AUC).
But instead to only apply the `predict()` I also applied the `predict_proba()` on the X_train data.

As you can se by the image, the observation 4 has 50 % of probability to give zero and 50%  to give one (according to `predict_proba()` function) however the `predict()` function classified it as zero

[Image with the dataframe where the first column is the result from predict_proba() function and the second column is the result from predict() column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cjlo0.png)

Did the predict() function sort as ZERO by "chance" or since it's zero or one, does it sort as zero because it comes first (as if order matters)?

I could not solve my doubts when analyzing the documentation of the functions (source: [https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7f9bad99d/sklearn/tree/\_classes.py#L476](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7f9bad99d/sklearn/tree/%5C_classes.py#L476))

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of binary classification the returned class is computed as follows

```
proba = self.tree_.predict(X)
...
return self.classes_.take(np.argmax(proba, axis=1), axis=0)
```

Reference: [sklearn code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7f9bad99d6e0a3e8ddf92a7e5561245224dab102/sklearn/tree/_classes.py#L507)

So basicaly the choice falls on `numpy.argmax`.

Let's look in the numpy [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) and read the following:

> Notes:
> In case of multiple occurrences of the maximum values, the indices corresponding to the first occurrence are returned.

So the final answer - in case of equal probabilities the first class is chosen always, which in case of binary classification corresponds to the negative label.

Comment: I'm glad! Please consider choosing this answer as accepted if it answered your question.